# How to get the position of a string in a JSON file?

Tags: python, json

I'm currently working on a project, written in python, for my class, which involves getting JSON data from a server.

My answer from the server looks something like this but is about 700000 characters long:

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": "123",
"result": [{
        "id": 666666,
        "date": 20170627,
        "startTime": 1120,
        "endTime": 1140,
        "lstype": "bs",
        "kl": [],
        "su": [],
        "ro": [{
            "id": 111,
            "name": "ROOM_2",
            "longname": "NAME_BBB"
        }],
        "lsnumber": 111,
        "statflags": "@"
    },

    {
        "id": 666667,
        "date": 20170626,
        "startTime": 950,
        "endTime": 1035,
        "kl": [{
            "id": 222,
            "name": "CLASS_1",
            "longname": "TEACHER_NAME_1, TEACHER_NAME_2"
        }],
        "su": [{
            "id": 33,
            "name": "XXX",
            "longname": "SUBJECT_1"
        }],
        "ro": [{
            "id": 44,
            "name": "ROOM_1",
            "longname": "NAME_AAA"
        }],
        "lsnumber": 55555,
        "statflags": "@"
    },

    {
        "id": 666668,
        "date": 20170627,
        "startTime": 1225,
        "endTime": 1310,
        "kl": [{
            "id": 666,
            "name": "CLASS_2",
            "longname": "TEACHER_NAME_3"
        }],
        "su": [{
            "id": 777,
            "name": "XXX",
            "longname": "SUBJECT_2"
        }],
        "ro": [{
            "id": 88,
            "name": "ROOM_3",
            "longname": "NAME_BBB, NAME_CCC"
        }],
        "lsnumber": 99999,
        "statflags": "@"
    },

    {
        "id": 666669,
        "date": 20170627,
        "startTime": 1500,
        "endTime": 1545,
        "kl": [{
                "id": 122,
                "name": "CLASS_1",
                "longname": "TEACHER_NAME_1, TEACHER_NAME_2"
            },
            {
                "id": 133,
                "name": "CLASS_3",
                "longname": "TEACHER_NAME_5, TEACHER_NAME_6"
            },
            {
                "id": 144,
                "name": "CLASS_4",
                "longname": "TEACHER_NAME_7 / TEACHER_NAME_8"
            }
        ],
        "su": [{
            "id": 55,
            "name": "XXX",
            "longname": "SUBJECT_3"
        }],
        "ro": [{
            "id": 66,
            "name": "ROOM_4",
            "longname": "NAME_DDD"
        }],
        "lsnumber": 7777,
        "statflags": "@"
    }

]
```

}

I need to get all positions of CLASS_1 in my JSON file so I can get the relating information (startTime, endTime, SUBJECT_X, ROOM_X and NAME_XXX) to display them in my application.

The output should look like this:

```
match 1:
950 till 1035
SUBJECT_1
ROOM_1
NAME_AAA

match 2:
1500 till 1545
SUBJECT_3
ROOM_4
NAME_DDD
```

Comment: your JSON is not valid !

Comment: I added 3 points at the end of it. Did you remove them?

Comment: lol, yes i did.

Comment: And there is a comma at the end.

Comment: Please use a [json validator](https://jsonlint.com/) and correct your json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading rather large json files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382253/reading-rather-large-json-files-in-python)

Comment: You can do it directly by running through the json Object like `for(var i=0; i<myJson.result.length; i++){ if(myJson.result[i].kl[0].name=="CLASS_1"){ ... Do something directly} }` or instead of "do something directly" you could e.g. collect the IDs in an array and later only run through the IDs which matched.... Is there a certain reason why e.g. kl and su and ro ... Are arrays [] though they only have 1 element?

Comment: JSON is valid now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this,

```
result = []
for item in data['result']:
    try:
        if item['kl'][0]['name'] == 'CLASS_1':
             result.append(['{} till {}'.format(item['startTime'], item['endTime']),
                      item['su'][0]['longname'], item['ro'][0]['name'],
                      item['ro'][0]['longname']])
    except:
        pass


In [11]: result
Out[11]: 
[['950 till 1035', 'SUBJECT_1', 'ROOM_1', 'NAME_AAA'],
 ['1500 till 1545', 'SUBJECT_3', 'ROOM_4', 'NAME_DDD']]
```

`data` would be the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Don't even try to parse the json as a string - convert it to Python with the `json` module (using `json.loads()` or `json.load()` depending on whether your source is a string or an opened file), then just iterate over the resulting object (a `dict` in this case) to get your values.