# Reading a chunk of "record oriented JSON file " in python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file where data is stored in records.

```
[{"count": 3, "articleTag": "muslims,myanmar,viral sach", "articleId": "587044", "deviceId": "0652c917-6241-4f1d-bad2-520ce8df0db5", "articleCategory": "VIDEO"}, {"count": 2, "articleTag": "vyakti vishesh,story,kim jong", "articleId": "587057", "deviceId": "0652c917-6241-4f1d-bad2-520ce8df0db5", "articleCategory": "VIDEO"}]
```

If i read this file `pd.read_json(filepath,orient='records')`. Then my system gets hanged. What's the best way to read file in chunks.

The file size would be in GB's. I need to read it in chunks.

Comment: How much memory does your system have?  How large is the largest file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading rather large json files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382253/reading-rather-large-json-files-in-python)