# Is there size limit for how much data python, json.loads, can import?

Tags: python, json, size

I tried to use the code below to import Json data into python. The file is 355MB.

```
import json
CATALOG = json.loads(open('Myfile.json').read())
```

I got error message as below:

> "File "D:.....py", line 8, in  CATALOG =
>   json.loads(open('Myfile.json').read()) File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\json__init__.py", line 339, in loads return
>   _default_decoder.decode(s) File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode obj,
>   end = self.scan_once(s, idx) MemoryError"

```
I down size the file to 100MB, it imported successfully. Is there a size limit for Python json? Or I can reset the limit?
```

Thanks,

Comment: Its how much memory is available on your machine. Python has a significant overhead for small objects like those typically found in json files. `pandas` has less overhead. I don't know whether you and fiddle with the json but its `read_json` method may work.

Comment: the way you do it, `read` and then `loads` means that the full 355mb file contents resides in memory. You'd be better off with `json.load(open('myfile.json'))`

Comment: Possible duplcate, including suggestions such as `ijson`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382253/reading-rather-large-json-files-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @tdelaney `json.load(fp, ...)` is just a wrapper around `json.loads(fp.read(), ...)` anyway.