# How to Read Just 10-20 Few Lines from Rather Big JSON File

Tags: python, json

I'd like to challenge to this Vision-Dialog Competition introduced on the following link:

https://visualdialog.org/challenge/2018

The link provides publicly open train dataset which has around 300MB of size and its format is JSON.

I just want to read few lines of this file so that I could just check which dialogues have been rounded between human and AI.

Is there any good way just to read few lines of JSON file using viewer or using python interaction shell- such as jupyter? Any medium is just fine.

--

I had tired mpu but it returns following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-dfebad8ac65a> in <module>()
----> 1 data = mpu.io.read("C:/Users/syyun/Downloads/visdial_0.9_train/visdial_0.9_train.json")

c:\users\syyun\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\mpu\io.py in read(filepath, **kwargs)
     83     elif filepath.lower().endswith('.json'):
     84         with open(filepath) as data_file:
---> 85             data = json.load(data_file, **kwargs)
     86         return data
     87     elif filepath.lower().endswith('.pickle'):

c:\users\syyun\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    294 
    295     """
--> 296     return loads(fp.read(),
    297         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    298         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,

downloadc:\users\syyun\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
     24 
     25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):
```

Comment: I guess you have a typo in the title (Jason = Jason)?

Comment: What is the problem in reading 300mb of json? Did you try it? (`pip install mpu` and then `import mpu.io; data = mpu.io.read("your path.json")`). I guess reading it takes less time than writing this question.

Comment: I followed your link and the training set is actually a zip-file: https://s3.amazonaws.com/visual-dialog/v0.9/visdial_0.9_train.zip. How about you download it, load it to memory and just pick the subset you are interested in? 300mb is not that much. But hey, this is my opinion.

Comment: @MartinThoma thx for your comment. but it returns memory error..

Comment: How much memory do you have? Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/10382359/562769 ? (I'll have a look at it when I'm at home... remind me, if I don't post something in ~15h)

Comment: @I have physical memory  16GB in system info of windows

Comment: Reading the `visdial_0.9_val.json` with `mpu` takes ~5GB peak on my machine. And it works

Comment: Reading `visdial_0.9_train.json`, my system consumed ~6GB at peak. Please note that I'm speaking of everything, not only the pythoh script (e.g. I have a game and the browser running as well)