# Error while saving Pandas Dataframe to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

When I am trying to save dataframe in json format. Getting below error. Size of df is 70+MB. pandas version : 0.23.4. Dataframe is having 90 columns and 165K records

df.to_json('df.json', orient='records')

```
    Could not reserve memory block
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/***/validate.py", line 70, in process_data
    df.to_json('df.json', orient='records')
  File "C:\***\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1891, in to_json
    index=index)
  File "C:\***\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 58, in to_json
    index=index).write()
  File "C:\***\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 101, in write
    self.date_format == 'iso', self.default_handler)
  File "C:\***\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 156, in _write
    iso_dates, default_handler)
  File "C:\***\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 112, in _write
    default_handler=default_handler
OverflowError: Could not reserve memory block
```

Comment: Please show an example structure and some data for the DF you are trying to convert

Comment: Probably you use 32 bit version of Python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336897/could-not-reserve-memory-block-import-json-error-in-python

Comment: I am using 64 bit version of python