# JSON Schema Generator Python

Tags: python, json

I am using this resource to generate the schema https://github.com/wolverdude/GenSON/

I have the below JSON File

```
{
 'name':'Sam',
},
{
 'name':'Jack',
}
```

so on ...

I am wondering how to iterate over a large JSON file. I want to parse each JSON file and pass it to GENSON to generate schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
     "name": {
       "type": [
        "string"
      ]
   }
},
  "required": [
    "name"
  ]
}
```

Comment: you question is not clear. What do you want exactly? Iterate over the second json for what?

Comment: I have a stream of JSON. I want to iterate over each JSON object so that I can generate schema using GENSON

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you should:

```
import json
from genson import SchemaBuilder

builder = SchemaBuilder()
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    datastore = json.load(f)
    builder.add_object(datastore )

builder.to_schema()
```

Where filename is your file path.

Comment: File size is too big (around 1GB)
I was wondering if there is a memory efficient way to this?

Comment: [Searched in 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382253/reading-rather-large-json-files-in-python)

Comment: IJSON is good for 1 Big JSON object. I have multiple json objects in one file.
thanks for sharing the link though