# Generating JSON schema from JSON file using GenSON

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to iterate over a JSON file and generate schema for it. I am using GENson tool. Similar to this question [JSON Schema Generator Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043331/json-schema-generator-python). But instead of

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
     "name": {
       "type": [
        "string"
      ]
   }
},
  "required": [
    "name"
  ]
}
```

I want the output to be:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
     "name": {
       "type": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

That is: **I don't want every property to be** `required`.

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: I was looking for some default options in the documentation which generates schema similar to my requirements. I could not find much. Then I wrote a python code myself to remove `required` key recursively given a schema