# Why RAM memory (16GB) is crashed while loading 6GB dictionary file into memory

Tags: python, json, dictionary, ram

I have a saved JSON file in my disk which is 6.1 GB. My requirement is to keep that dictionary file memory so that I can replace keys with values in another file.

But I ended up getting Memory error each time when I try to do this step. Can anybody help me load dictionary without getting memory error?

Code is as follows:

```
with open('file_name.json') as f:
    dictionary = json.load(f)
```

Comment: 6Gb of JSON data on disk doesn't mean 6Gb of Python objects in memory.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382253/reading-rather-large-json-files-in-python) should help you

Comment: You have multiple overheads applied in this case: 1/ you have 6Gb of JSON in ASCII text file format, which depending on the internal structure of Python dictionaries, can take more than 6Gb of RAM (as @jonrsharpe said). 2/ the OS and other software also consume RAM, so you can't consider having 16Gb of usable RAM. 3/ If Python requires that the memory needed for your dictionary must be contiguous, then it might be difficult for your system to provide such a big contiguous chunk of RAM

Comment: If the amount of input data is high and random access to it is required, I would suggest other approaches like, an SQLite-based processing, loading only partial data from the disk, caching a subset of your data instead of loading it all, etc

Answer (score 0):

Your computer won't give acces to any amount of RAM to a process. You should check the limit on your system what the limit is for your Python process, information [there](https://airbrake.io/blog/python-exception-handling/memoryerror#:%7E:text=The%20specific%20maximum%20memory%20allocation,by%20your%20available%20system%20memory.).