# Memory error while parsing huge JSON file

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse a huge 12 GB JSON file with almost 5 million lines(each one is an object) in python and store it to a database. I'm using **ijson** and multiprocessing in order to run it faster. Here is the code

```
def parse(paper):
    global mydata
 
    if 'type' not in paper["venue"]:
        venue = Venues(venue_raw = paper["venue"]["raw"])
        venue.save()
    else:
        venue = Venues(venue_raw = paper["venue"]["raw"], venue_type = paper["venue"]["type"])
        venue.save()
    paper1 = Papers(paper_id = paper["id"],paper_title = paper["title"],venue = venue)
    paper1.save()
            
    paper_authors = paper["authors"]
    paper_authors_json = json.dumps(paper_authors)
    obj = ijson.items(paper_authors_json,'item')
    for author in obj:
        mydata = mydata.append({'author_id': author["id"] , 'venue_raw': venue.venue_raw, 'year' : paper["year"],'number_of_times': 1},ignore_index=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(4)
 
    filename = 'C:/Users/dintz/Documents/finaldata/dblp.v12.json'
    with open(filename,encoding='UTF-8') as infile:
        papers = ijson.items(infile, 'item')   
        for paper in papers:
            p.apply_async(parse,(paper,))
    
            
    
    p.close()
    p.join()
            
    
 
    mydata = mydata.groupby(by=['author_id','venue_raw','year'], axis=0, as_index = False).sum()
    mydata = mydata.groupby(by = ['author_id','venue_raw'], axis=0, as_index = False, group_keys = False).apply(lambda x: sum((1+x.year-x.year.min())*numpy.log10(x.number_of_times+1)))
    df = mydata.index.to_frame(index = False)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'author_id':df["author_id"],'venue_raw':df["venue_raw"],'rating':mydata.values[:,2]})
    
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        author_id = row['author_id']
        venue = Venues.objects.get(venue_raw = row['venue_raw'])
        rating = Ratings(author_id = author_id, venue = venue, rating = row['rating'])
        rating.save()
```

However I get the following error without knowing the reason
[image]

Can somebody help me?

Comment: how much is your RAM

Comment: You're probably not going to have a good time trying to use Pandas dataframes for this, if you want to be memory-frugal.

Comment: Also, using a `multiprocessing.Pool()` means your `mydata` will not be global across those  multiple processes.

Comment: You should probably consider writing a script that turns your data into flat CSV/TSV files that you can import into your (apparently Django-modeled) database using the `LOAD INFILE` equivalent of your database.

Comment: @Tuqay My RAM is 8 GB

Comment: @ΔημήτριοςΙντζελερ , it is obvious that you are running out of memory. You can't just load 12 GB file into 8 GB ram. you have to find a way to parse it in parts. I suggest looking at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382253/reading-rather-large-json-files-in-python

Comment: @Tuqay Your link discusses using `ijson`, which is what OP is already doing.

Comment: There were some other options, so i left a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to make quite some extrapolations and assumptions, but it looks like

- you're using Django
- you want to populate an SQL database with venue, paper and author data
- you want to then do some analysis using Pandas

Populating your SQL database can be done pretty neatly with something like the following.

- I added the `tqdm` package so you get a progress indication.
- This assumes there's a `PaperAuthor` model that links papers and authors.
- Unlike the original code, this will not save duplicate `Venue`s in the database.
- You can see I replaced `get_or_create` and `create` with stubs to make this runnable without the database models (or indeed, without Django), just having [the dataset you're using](https://www.kaggle.com/mathurinache/citation-network-dataset) available.

On my machine, this consumes practically no memory, as the records are (or would be) dumped into the SQL database, not into an ever-growing, fragmenting dataframe in memory.

The Pandas processing is left as an exercise for the reader ;-), but I'd imagine it'd involve `pd.read_sql()` to read this preprocessed data from the database.

```
import multiprocessing

import ijson
import tqdm


def get_or_create(model, **kwargs):
    # Actual Django statement:
    # return model.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)
    return (None, True)


def create(model, **kwargs):
    # Actual Django statement:
    # return model.objects.create(**kwargs)
    return None


Venue = "Venue"
Paper = "Paper"
PaperAuthor = "PaperAuthor"


def parse(paper):
    venue_name = paper["venue"]["raw"]
    venue_type = paper["venue"].get("type")
    venue, _ = get_or_create(Venue, venue_raw=venue_name, venue_type=venue_type)
    paper_obj = create(Paper, paper_id=paper["id"], paper_title=paper["title"], venue=venue)
    for author in paper["authors"]:
        create(PaperAuthor, paper=paper_obj, author_id=author["id"], year=paper["year"])


def main():
    filename = "F:/dblp.v12.json"
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p, open(filename, encoding="UTF-8") as infile:
        for result in tqdm.tqdm(p.imap_unordered(parse, ijson.items(infile, "item"), chunksize=64)):
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I get this error
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: database is locked`
Seems like I must run it without multiprocessing and just wait for a long time :(

Comment: You get `database is locked` only on SQLite databases. Try another database such as MySQL or PostgreSQL, or try running SQLite in WAL mode: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24018

Comment: It worked perfectrly fine but when i try to convert the database to pandas with `pd.DataFrame.from_records(Log.objects.all().values())` I get the following error `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 227. MiB for an array with shape (14852428,) and data type complex128`. I use windows

Comment: You need more memory, then. Alternatively, dump the records to CSV/HDF5/Parquet/... and load that into Pandas.