# How to handle huge JSON files?

Tags: python, json, large-files

My JSON file is 5.5 MB (annotations file of Object365 dataset for object detection models). My Python program can't even read it as a simple text file.

```
 def ob365_converter(inputJsonFile, datasetPath):
    text = readFileLine(inputJsonFile)
    print("text:")
    print(text[0:100])
    datasetJson = json.loads(text)
    print("dataset loaded")
    for item in datasetJson["annotations"]:
        #Do some operations
        . . .
 
    def readFileLine(filePath):
        p = Path(filePath)
        if not p.is_file():
            print("%s is not a file", filePath)
            return ""
        with open(filePath, "r") as f:
            text = f.readline()
        return text
```

The output doesn't show even the first message "text:". I also tried with same result the following:

```
print ("A")
f = open(inputJsonFile, 'r')
datasetJson = json.load(f)
f.close()
print ("B")
```

How to handle huge JSON files in Python?

Comment: The problem seems to be in  `readFileLine`, could you show us how you've coded it, or give us more info about the library it's from?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382253/reading-rather-large-json-files-in-python

Comment: What happens when you run your second code example?

Comment: The second code prints "A" followed by "Killed".

Comment: 5.5 MB can not be considered as "huge" - isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big size of json file requires too much source to be handled. As mentioned in @cizario's link, it should be used some stream logic that access json objects without storing all the content of the file.

One py library that works in streaming can be found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.