# convert json to table and avoid memory error

Tags: python, json

I have a large json file with 38 GB as this structure:

```
{"Text": [

    {
        "a" : 6,
        "b" : 2022,
        "c" : 11,
        "d" : "2022-11-24", 
        "e" : "567",
        "f" : "ww", 
        "i" : "00",  
        "j" : 4,
        "k" : "y",
        "l" : null,
        "m" : 3,
        "n" : 7,
        "o" : "54",
        "b" : null,
        "q" : "yes",
        "r" : 77,
        "c" : "yes",
        "t" : 6,
        "y" : 8,
        "v" : "yy",
        "w" : "yy",
        "x" : "o",
        "y" : "100                                                                                                                          ",

        "z" : "r"

    },{...},{....}

    ]}
```

so I have created this code to convert the json to dataFrame, but I get memory error.

> ```
>  df=pd.DataFrame([])
> with open('data.json',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
>     l=f.read()
>     c=json.loads(l)
>     v=list(c.keys())[0]
>     data=(c[v])
>
>     for line in itertools.islice(data,2):
>         json_nor=json_normalize(line)
>         df=df.append(json_nor, ignore_index = True)
> ```

any advice how to convert them and avoid memory error?

Comment: have you tried **pandas.read_json()** ?

Comment: yes it is gives me this error "ValueError: Expected object or value"
 , I think i need to access "Text" index first

Comment: update: the error gone after removed "lines=True", but the memory error still there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading rather large JSON files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382253/reading-rather-large-json-files)