# Efficiently loading ZCTAs from a shape file

Tags: google-maps, geojson, zipcode

I'm working on an google map application that uses a geojson file that stores the ZCTA (Zip Code Tabulation Areas) of states.  These files are fairly large and take some time to load so I was trying to find ways to reduce the loading time of the geoJson file.

I have looked at this question here:
[Is there a memory efficient and fast way to load big json files in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400643/is-there-a-memory-efficient-and-fast-way-to-load-big-json-files-in-python)

so I am aware that reducing the loading time isn't easy to do.

but I came across this link that quickly loads ZCTA:
http://www.trulia.com/home_prices/

So my question is this: What has the developer done on this site to quickly load the ZCTA data? Can anyone see offhand how it was done?

Comment: Pre-load it and store it in memory. You may have to write a custom, optimized data structure to get it to fit, depending on the data. (How large are we talking?)

Comment: Use one of the Google Maps Layers that renders with tiles.  FusionTablesLayer would probably be simplest.  Either that or render the tiles yourself.  John Coryat ([maps.huge.info](http://maps.huge.info/)) did a bunch of work in this area at one point.

Comment: Thank you very much for these answers.  This question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking, "how do I write the user interface for a GIS that will offer high performance?"

The developer of this website is not storing this information in a JSON and then loading it each time in response to each user's clicks. The developer is probably storing all of these objects in memory. To make things even faster, the developer has probably created the various KML files for the Google map in advance. The developer may be interfacing directly with Google, or may be using a commercial GIS that has an output format that employs Google Maps.

For example, you might check out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190709/arcgis-to-google-maps.