# MemoryError while reading JSON from txt file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have 3 txt files (`file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt`),  that contains JSON formatted data. The size of the files like something like this:

```
file1 = 104.55 Mb
file2 = 104.68 Mb
file3 = 104.49 Mb
```

I can open and read `file1` and `file3` without any problems, but when I try to open `file2` I'm getting a `MemoryError` despite its size is almost the same as the others, the difference is less than `200KB`.

Here is my implementation for opening the files:

```
with open(file1.txt, encoding="utf-8") as f:
    jsonContent = json.load(f)

json_data = json.dumps(jsonContent)
file_data = json.loads(json_data)
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could tell me what can cause this issue, because everything seems fine for me and I can't believe that 200KB is the reason. Am I doing something wrong in my code or it is what it looks like, I don't have enough memory?

Comment: Do you want to load all of them together?

Comment: @Kasramvd No. I would like to load one file always.

Answer (score 0):

It's always hard to say exactly what's causing the issue; but this question has been asked before, usually replied to with links to 
[iJSON](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/) or [json streamer](https://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/json-streamer).

I won't say that's the defacto solution for you, but the question is common. If you go the iJSON route, please look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17326199/3945466) and the thread around it.