# How to parse a multi-gigabyte JSON file - Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, amazon-s3, bigdata

I am getting a multi-gigabyte json file from an S3 bucket and need to convert the json file into a python dictionary. How can this be done in python 2.7?

Comment: Sure, if you have a 64 bit Python installation and many GB of RAM (or if the format is actually a bunch of lines of JSON, not a single JSON object). What have you tried? What is the exact data format? How much RAM do you have available? Why are you writing new code for Python 2.7 instead of moving to Python 3?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do such a thing, you can use `ijson`[https://github.com/isagalaev/ijson]. But I bet its a line-by-line` json` file and not one big `json` object which makes things more reasonable (try `map(json.loads, lines)`)

Comment: Did `json.load` actually fail with a memory error?

Comment: I have yet to try an approach. Didn't want to follow down a path only to be stopped. @kabanus are you saying there is no limit to `json.load`? I can simply do `json.load(file.read())`?

Comment: @GaryHoliday I do not know.  Something like `with open('giantfile.json') as fd: json.load(fd)`

Comment: You need to `import json` if that was not clear. If it is easy to test I would try that first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a memory efficient and fast way to load big json files in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400643/is-there-a-memory-efficient-and-fast-way-to-load-big-json-files-in-python)