# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 13 (char 15).My json file is very big i.e., 5GB. Please suggest any solution

Tags: json

A = json.load(open('InputFile.json')) Got an error JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 13 (char 15)

Comment: Which is line 2? Which is column 13?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a memory efficient and fast way to load big json files in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400643/is-there-a-memory-efficient-and-fast-way-to-load-big-json-files-in-python)