# Efficiently loading a large Amazon product review dataset into MongoDB using Apache Spark

Tags: json, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I'm working on a project where I need to load a large Amazon product dataset (126 GB when decompressed) into MongoDB using Apache Spark. The dataset is in line-separated JSON format.

How can I optimize the data loading process while considering the schema of the dataset and the #structure of the MongoDB collections?

```python
import json
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Set up the MongoDB connector
mongo_connector = "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1"

# Initialize the Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("AmazonReviewsToMongoDB") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", mongo_connector) \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/amazon_reviews.reviews") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/amazon_reviews.reviews") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Read the compressed dataset
reviews_rdd = (
    spark.sparkContext.textFile(r"X:/reviews.json.gz")
    .map(json.loads)
)

# Convert the RDD to a DataFrame
reviews_df = reviews_rdd.toDF()

# Save the DataFrame to MongoDB
reviews_df.write.format("mongo").mode("overwrite").save()
```

I don't think so this code will work efficiently - i.e read data in minimum time.

Comment: I've had great success using [`mongoimport`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/ "link to mongoimport docs -->").  Perhaps  it will work for you too.

Comment: the file is present in json.gz format and gzip isnot working with my mongoimport plus i cannot decompress the file due to its huge size (126 GB after decompressing)

Comment: You can pipe the output of the decompressor into `mongoimport`.

Comment: i have to load the dataset using apache spark (bcz of uni project)
and as of rn im not able to get anywhere
(so mongoimport is out of question)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly read it as a json file, no need to read it as text file rdd and then do the conversion.
Have you tried the below command?

```
df = spark.read.json("path of the file")
```

Comment: yes it works efficiently but when im writing the resultant df to mongodb
it ends up taking all space in C  and mongodb crashes then (script too)

Comment: I wrote the data into mongodb, it is huge (around 43 gb)
Now i want to read it and convert it into pandas df
what is the most efficient way?

Comment: I have not used Pandas DF, Check out the below stack overflow answer, it might help.      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800463/read-large-json-file-with-index-format-into-pandas-dataframe/61808370#61808370

Comment: @HammadJavaid, was your issue issue resolved?

Comment: Yes. First, i defined the schema then i reduced the dataset size, repartitioned it and used the following while writing to MongoDB:
spark.mongodb.output.createCollectionOptions
spark.mongodb.output.batchSize
spark.mongodb.output.bulk.ordered

Comment: Oh ok, good to know the way u had resolved it.