# Processing a big file in python (>60gb)

Tags: python, text-processing

i have a text file **(>= 60Gig)** and record's in it are like this :

```
{"index": {"_type": "_doc", "_id": "bLcy4m8BAObvGO9GALME"}}
{"message":"{\"_\":\"user\",\"pFlags\":{\"contact\":true},\"flags\":2135,\"id\":816704468,\"access_hash\":\"788468819702098896\",\"first_name\":\"a\",\"last_name\":\"b\",\"phone\":\"123\",\"status\":{\"_\":\"userStatusOffline\",\"was_online\":132}}","phone":"12","@version":"1","typ":"telegram_contacts","access_hash":"123","id":816704468,"@timestamp":"2020-01-26T13:53:29.467Z","path":"/home/user/mirror_01/users_5d6ca02e7e736a7fc700df8c.log","type":"redis","flags":2135,"host":"ubuntu","imported_from":"telegram_contacts"}

{"index": {"_type": "_doc", "_id": "Z7cy4m8BAObvGO9GALME"}}
{"message":"{\"_\":\"user\",\"pFlags\":{\"contact\":true},\"flags\":2143,\"id\":323586643,\"access_hash\":\"8315858910992970114\",\"first_name\":\"bv\",\"last_name\":\"nj\",\"username\":\"kj\",\"phone\":\"123\",\"status\":{\"_\":\"userStatusRecently\"}}","phone":"123","@version":"1","typ":"telegram_contacts","access_hash":"8315858910992970114","id":323586643,"@timestamp":"2020-01-26T13:53:29.469Z","path":"/home/user/mirror_01/users_5d6ca02e7e736a7fc700df8c.log","username":"mbnab","type":"redis","flags":2143,"host":"ubuntu","imported_from":"telegram_contacts"}
```

I have a few questions regarding this:

1. Is this a valid JSON file?
2. Can python process a file of this size? Or should I convert it somehow to Access or Excel file?

These are some SO posts I found useful:

- [Is there a memory efficient and fast way to load big json files in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400643/is-there-a-memory-efficient-and-fast-way-to-load-big-json-files-in-python)
- [Reading rather large json files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382253/reading-rather-large-json-files-in-python)

But still need help.

Comment: I don't think that is json.

Comment: @Yatin me too . do you think i should make a template for that ?

Comment: Is the value of "message" just json that has been saved as a string and with the " escaped?

Comment: @MichaelC yes sir . this is an exact record.

Comment: Processing a file this size is possible with python.... but what do you want to do with it exactly? And what have you tried?

Comment: @MichaelC Search in it.Based on params

Comment: i try to create a template to read file and save it on Excel but couldn't

Answer (score 0):

You can work through the file line by line and extract the information you need.

```
with open('largefile.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Extract what you need from that line of text here
        print(line)
```

For example, to read things You can work through the file line by line and extract the information you need.

```
with open('largefile.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # For example, to interpret the string as json, and read 
        # it in as a dictionary, do 
        if line.strip():  # check there is something on the line
            data = json.loads(line)
            # in your case, to fix the value for "message" do
            if 'message' in data: 
                data['message'] = json.loads(data['message']) 
            # extract information you need here
```

I expect there's a lot more work to extract the information you need, but I hope this gets you started. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Please accept it as correct if it solved your problem.