# How can I efficiently parse large JSON files in Python without running into memory issues

Tags: python, json

How can I efficiently parse large JSON files in Python without running into memory issues

I am working on a project where I need to process large JSON files containing hundreds of thousands of records in Python. However, when I try to load the entire JSON file into memory using libraries like json or pandas, I encounter memory issues due to the size of the file. I need a more efficient way to parse these large JSON files without consuming excessive memory. Additionally, I would like to be able to extract specific data from the JSON files, such as certain fields or subsets of records, without having to load the entire file into memory. What are some strategies or libraries I can use to handle this efficiently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a memory efficient and fast way to load big JSON files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400643/is-there-a-memory-efficient-and-fast-way-to-load-big-json-files)