How can I improve the performance of my Python script for processing large JSON files?
I am working on a Python script that processes large JSON files (~500MB) to extract specific data and save it into a CSV format. The script works, but it is slow, especially for files with nested JSON objects. Here's a simplified version of my code:
import json  
import csv  

def process_json(file_path):  
    with open(file_path, 'r') as json_file:  
        data = json.load(json_file)  

    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:  
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)  
        writer.writerow(['field1', 'field2', 'field3'])  

        for record in data:  
            writer.writerow([record['field1'], record['field2'], record['field3']])  

process_json('large_file.json')  

I've tried using json.load() and then iterating through the data, but it seems to consume a lot of memory and time. I came across the json module's iterparse, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my use case.
My questions are:

Is there a more memory-efficient way to process large JSON files in Python?
Would libraries like pandas or ujson provide significant performance benefits for this task?
How can I handle nested JSON objects more efficiently while writing to CSV?

Environment:

Python 3.10
Windows 11


Hi! Please, do a small research before posting a question. You will find that people might have already asked something similar. In this case, some answers to this same question are already available in these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2400643/6279885 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/10382253/6279885

~500MB of JSON is the actual problem. THis format has not been designed for that (nor performance in mind). You should not use it but a better-structured binary format. Also please note that each CPython object typically takes 24 bytes (+8 byte per object reference) so storing millions of such object will take a significant space. Loading everything into memory is the second problem. As for pandas, no, this is a dataframe library, not one to read JSON files.

show an actual example of the file to be converted, also, provide an example of expected output that includes nested json entries - you may need to manually do that if you are unable to provide working code at this time.

Do you control the source format? if so you can switch from a large json payload that is a list of dictionaries to lines of json dictionaries. you can then stream read and stream write these lines without loading the entire file at once.
